# Eigen equivalent of find() in Matlab

Tags: find, eigen

I'm trying to write my code from Matlab to c++ using Eigen, I have a boolean matrix

```
A << 1 0 0
     0 1 0
     1 1 0
```

I'm using find function in Matlab to get the indices of non-zero values `find (A) --> 1 3 5 6`, how to do the same think with Eigen ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today that is not implemented inside Eigen. So essentially, you need to loop through your matrix manually. Something like this should work (Eigen will start indexing at 0, of course):

```
Eigen::Matrix<bool, ....> A;
std::vector<Eigen::Index> idxs;
for(Eigen::Index i=0; i<A.size(); ++i)
    if(A(i))
        idxs.push_back(i);
```

Comment: Thanks chtz, I'm trying what you propose but I'm getting an error in `push_back`, here's the example :
`MatrixXd A(3,3);
  
      A << 1, 0, 0,
           0, 1, 0,
           1, 1, 0;   
           
      cout << A << endl;   
      
      VectorXd::Index idxs;  
      for(Index i=0; i<A.size(); ++i){  
        if(A(i))  
         idxs.push_back(i);  
      }`

Comment: You can't `push_back` into an `Index`, you need to create a `std::vector<Eigen::Index>` or equivalent for that.

Comment: Please chtz can you explain what this line does, `std::vector<Eigen::Index>` you used a vector container with Eigen ??

Comment: Thanks to @chtz, I didn't know about STL containers in Eigen, works perfectly.

Comment: `Eigen::Index` is just a typedef for `std::ptrdiff_t`. You can also just write `int` (as long as you have less than 2^31 elements in your matrix ...)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to you should see [libigl](https://libigl.github.io/). libigl is a simple C++ geometry processing library.  It has a wide functionality for matrix manipulation which make Eigen feel a lot more like MATLAB.

And you can check [this website](https://igl.ethz.ch/projects/libigl/matlab-to-eigen.html) to see [matlab to eigen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbe78.png).

As a suggestion from [@ChristianB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14794380/christianb), i added an image to show matlab to eigen.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this library/link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.